# Modificadores de acceso en componentes de una GUI

Tags: java, diseño

Desde el punto de vista de las buenas prácticas de diseño e ingeniería ¿Es correcto o necesario poner cada componente de la GUI como privado? Por ejemplo, los JTextField, JButton, etc.

Tomando en cuenta que este usando el patrón MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Las GUI están basadas en la programación orientada a objetos, y uno de sus fundamentos es la encapsulación.

La encapsulación se basa en el ocultamiento de estados de las variables.

La respuesta varía según el caso:

- **VARIABLES PRIVADAS:** Solamente son visibles dentro de la clase en las
  que residen.
- **VARIABLES PROTEGIDAS:** Visibles por clases del mismo    paquete, o en
  el caso en el que una clase herede de otra en la que    reside una
  variable "protected".
- **VARIABLES PUBLICAS:** Visibles dentro    y fuera del paquete, su acceso
  es publico.

Para mas información:

[Encapsulamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_(inform%C3%A1tica))

[Programación orientada a objetos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_orientada_a_objetos#Conceptos_fundamentales)

Comment: Gracias. Bueno esos conceptos si los conozco, pero en sí me refiero específicamente en las clases GUI. O dicho en otras palabras, sí tengo una clase controller que implementa el manejador de eventos, cuál es la forma correcta de acceder al contenido de los componentes del GUU